# A proper way to build a robust API for the social application?

Tags: php, android, ios, web-services, api

There is an existing social web app and the client now wants to make mobile applications for it. We need to make an API which will be robust and which will not hang down when 100k existing users start using these mobile apps.

Do you have suggestion about the proper way to build this API?

We have made hundreds of APIs in the past which also used 100k users. But this app is a bit specific and we anticipate many, many more concurrent API requests, 20 times more concurrent requests then ever in the past.

That is why I am reluctant to using our "standard" API logic before I see if anyone here can advise some good tactics.

On the high level, there will be a database on the server and an API layer which will handle all the communication.

Answer (score 0):

In short: look at your hardware solution.

Try to minimize IO where possible. If possible pack as many included resources you need for the app into one payload, server side, then push it to the client in one go. You don't want hundreds of includes on the client side really.

One idea is monitor how many simultaneous requests are going on and if it gets too much for the threshold (you can do sims to find out what the threshold of pain is) start buffering the requests in a queue to ensure each user gets a smooth experience. Maybe they'll wait longer in the begining but once loading starts it will be smooth rather than bits of the application loading. The most annoying thing for a user is not knowing if the thing has finished loading or not, or have it load half way and then stop.

Ultimately though, you'll need to look at the hardware solution. Look at the set up of hardware LBs and servers with SSD drives if it's IO intensive.